# Помощь в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Установил wordpress, woocommerce. Мне надо, чтобы клиент сам выбирал кол-во одного товара(при покупке) ползунком! Есть ли такой плагин? Если нету, то подскажите, что мне делать?

Comment: Плагина такого не знаю, а что делать - понятно. Осваивайте jQuery и рисуйте ползунок.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Используйте `<input type="range">`